# the difference **between** A, B and C

Tags: word-usage

Cambridge Dictionary grammar tutorial [says](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/between-or-among)

> We use **between** to refer to two things which are clearly separated. We use among to talk about things which are not clearly separated because they are part of a group or crowd or mass of objects

Imagine that, Chollet and Schmidhuber are friends, Schmidhuber is aware of the difference among A, B and C while Chollet is not.

Chollet asks about that and Schmidhuber replies

> the difference **among** A, B and C

So far so good. If Schmidhuber says

> the difference **between** A, B and C

is it grammatical? If not, is it idiomatic in everyday speaking?

Comment: 'The difference between A, B and C' sounds idiomatic to me. Check out: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37636/between-vs-among and  https://www.grammar-monster.com/easily_confused/between_among.htm

Comment: This has been explained far better then I ever could. https://english.stackexchange.com/a/37640/379412

Comment: Native English speakers do not typically say "the difference among".